# sending mail using java from pc to mobile

Tags: java

```
final String username = "<mail_name>";
final String password = "<password>";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

try {

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("<mail_from>@gmail.com"));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse("<mail_to>@gmail.com"));
message.setSubject("Test Subject");
message.setText("Test");

Transport.send(message);

System.out.println("Done");

 } catch (MessagingException e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I have tried this code for sending mail from pc to mobile but it giving error while compiling . Can any one help me to send mail?

Comment: what is the error you got?

Answer (score 1):

```
  public class sendmail{
  public static void mail(String args[]){
   final String fromEmail = ""; //requires valid gmail id
        final String password = ""; // correct password for gmail id
        final String toEmail = "" // can be any email id          
        System.out.println("SSLEmail Start");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); //SSL Port
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); //SSL Factory Class
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //Enabling SMTP Authentication
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); //SMTP Port
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
        System.out.println("Session created");
        String subject = "";//subject here

            String body = "";//mail body here
            sendEmail(session, toEmail, subject, body);
       }
        public static void sendEmail(Session session, String toEmail, String subject, String body) {
    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        //set message headers
        msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
        msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
        msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@anyname.com", "any name"));
        msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
        msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        msg.setText(body, "UTF-8");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
        System.out.println("Message is ready");
        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What is mean by PC to Mobile. PC & mobile both are hardware devices to access the mail.Please follow the below link for sending mail in java using java mail API via gmail SMTP.
http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/